# C++ iterators problem

Tags: c++, iterator, vector

I'm working with iterators on C++ and I'm having some trouble here. It says "Debug Assertion Failed" on expression (this->_Has_container()) on line interIterator++.
Distance list is a vector< vector< DistanceNode > >. What I'm I doing wrong?

```
vector< vector<DistanceNode> >::iterator externIterator = distanceList.begin();

   while (externIterator != distanceList.end()) {

    vector<DistanceNode>::iterator interIterator = externIterator->begin();

        while (interIterator != externIterator->end()){

          if (interIterator->getReference() == tmp){

     //remove element pointed by interIterator
     externIterator->erase(interIterator);             

          } // if
    interIterator++;
  } // while
  externIterator++;
   } // while
```

Comment: It's not the cause of the error, but you should use pre-increment to advance your iterators - ++interIterator.

Comment: Not that it really matters performance wise, it's optimized away by most compilers.

Answer (score 13):

vector's `erase()` returns a new iterator to the next element.  All iterators to the erased element *and to elements after it* become invalidated.  Your loop ignores this, however, and continues to use `interIterator`.

Your code should look something like this:

```
if (condition)
    interIterator = externIterator->erase(interIterator);
else
    ++interIterator;  // (generally better practice to use pre-increment)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove elements from a sequence container while iterating over it — at least not the way you are doing it — because calling `erase` invalidates the iterator. You should assign the return value from `erase` to the iterator and suppress the increment:

```
while (interIterator != externIterator->end()){
   if (interIterator->getReference() == tmp){
       interIterator = externIterator->erase(interIterator);             
   } else {
       ++interIterator;
   }
}
```

Also, never use post-increment (i++) when pre-increment (++i) will do.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the liberty to rewrite the code:

```
class ByReference: public std::unary_function<bool, DistanceNode>
{
public:
  explicit ByReference(const Reference& r): mReference(r) {}
  bool operator()(const DistanceNode& node) const
  {
    return node.getReference() == r;
  }
private:
  Reference mReference;
};

typedef std::vector< std::vector< DistanceNode > >::iterator iterator_t;

for (iterator_t it = dl.begin(), end = dl.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  it->erase(
     std::remove_if(it->begin(), it->end(), ByReference(tmp)),
     it->end()
  );
}
```

Why ?

- The first loop (`externIterator`) iterates over a full range of elements without ever modifying the range itself, it's what a `for` is for, this way you won't forget to increment (admittedly a `for_each` would be better, but the syntax can be awkward)
- The second loop is tricky: simply speaking you're actually cutting the branch you're sitting on when you call `erase`, which requires jumping around (using the value returned). In this case the operation you want to accomplish (purging the list according to a certain criteria) is exactly what the `remove-erase` idiom is tailored for.

Note that the code could be tidied up if we had true lambda support at our disposal. In C++0x we would write:

```
std::for_each(distanceList.begin(), distanceList.end(),
  [const& tmp](std::vector<DistanceNode>& vec)
  {
    vec.erase(
      std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        [const& tmp](const DistanceNode& dn) { return dn.getReference() == tmp; }
      ),
      vec.end()
    );
  }
);
```

As you can see, we don't see any iterator incrementing / dereferencing taking place any longer, it's all wrapped in dedicated algorithms which ensure that everything is handled appropriately.

I'll grant you the syntax looks strange, but I guess it's because we are not used to it yet.