# Erase operation on vector not working

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, vector

I am new to C++ and I am having difficulties with getting the vector.erase operation to work.

I have a database class as such:

```
template <class T> class Database
{
    protected:
        std::vector<T> m_database;
        int m_counter;
    public:
        Database();
        virtual ~Database();

        // Accessor Methods.
        T& getObject(int objectId);
        bool exists(int objectId);

        // Mutator Methods.
        void add(T Object);
        void del(int objectId);
};
```

and in practice, I am using the code as such:

```
Database<Account> accountDatabase;
```

`Account` is a base class, with two derived classes, `ChequingAccount` and `SavingsAccount`.

I am inserting accounts, regardless of type (could be `Account`, `ChequingAccount`, `SavingsAccount`) into this database using:

```
template <class T> void Database<T>::add(T object)
{
    m_database.push_back(object);
    ++m_counter;
}
```

However, I am having issues with my delete operation. I am searching for a corresponding `objectId` and then deleting it from the vector.

```
// Deletes the specified object from the database.
template <class T> void Database<T>::del(int objectId)
{
    std::vector<T>& database             = m_database;
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = database.begin();

    while (it != database.end()) {
        if ((*it).getId() == objectId) {
            it = database.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the delete operation is not working at all. I am also having issues pulling a derived class from the database, as everything is being pulled out as an `Account` type. I believe these two issues are tied to my noob C++ skills and bad design.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**

By not working, I mean the object is not deleted from the database. I apologize for any confusion.

The Account classes:

```
class Account
{
    protected:
        int m_id;
        double m_balance;
        std::string m_name, m_type;
    public:
        Account(int id, int userId, double balance = 0, std::string name = ""); // Constructor.
        ~Account(); // Destructor.

        // Accessor Methods.
        // This returns m_id AKA objectId
        int getId() const;
}

class ChequingAccount: public Account
{
    public:
        ChequingAccount(int id, int userId, double balance, std::string name) : Account(id, userId, balance, name) {}
}

class SavingsAccount: public Account
{
    public:
        SavingsAccount(int id, int userId, double balance, std::string name) : Account(id, userId, balance, name) {}
}
```

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "not working at all"? 2. Why not use `std::remove`?

Comment: also posting Account could be helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [deleting while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901356/deleting-while-iterating)

Comment: @Raymond This is slightly different because the user is correctly reassigning the iterator result from the call to `std::vector<t>::erase(iterator)`

Comment: Your `del()` looks fine so maybe check if your `id` is correct?

Comment: Also you can't store derived class objects in there unless you are storing pointers rather than the objects themselves.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I clarified a bit more. Thanks for the insight Galik, I would like to store the derived classes, seems like I need to use pointers.

Comment: I have included my `Account` classes to the question if it helps

Comment: How does one get an object ID?  You have methods that have ID parameters, but none that return one.

Comment: You can replace `m_counter` with `m_database.size()`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your remove function would be far better in terms of `std::remove_if`:

```
auto endIterator = std::remove_if(m_database.begin(), m_database.end(),
    [=](T const& entry) { return entry.getId() == objectId; }
    );
m_database.erase(endIterator, m_database.end());
```

That said, your version does not look incorrect, just inefficient. What about it "doesn't work"? I do note that you maintain a separate object ID in your database but never actually put that ID into the objects you store.

Comment: the old 'erase/remove' idiom

Comment: Assuming that my method is "correct", it should be my objectId giving me problems?

Comment: @user3745117 you never show how the ID gets into T so we have no idea.

Comment: @BillyONeal I have edited my question to include those classes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `del` function looks correct, only suggestion is instead of:

```
(*it).getId()
```

you can/should use:

```
it->getId()
```

which is simpler and more readable. So culprit is somewhere else. As for issue, that everything is pulled as `Account` type, you have slicing problem, details read here [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

The fact that you make your class `Database` a template does not change anything, you probably misunderstand what template does. Your `Database<Account>` is nothing more than as you would use `Account` instead of `T` and not use template at all, and you insert objects, inherited from `Account` by value.

Comment: Yes, I suspected this was the case for losing the derived type. I could not get a vector of pointers working properly, however. I guess I shall try again