# Erasing a pointer from a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to erase a pointer to an object, but I keep crashing the console (PS2), I don't get any errors due to the way the console is set up, so I'm not quite sure what is going on.

I've listed the two lines that error, this didn't error until I added these lines.

```
    for(listIter = m_downDirectionList.begin(); listIter != m_downDirectionList.end(); listIter++)
    {
        Projectile* proj = dynamic_cast<Projectile*>(*listIter);

        if (proj->getZWorldCoord() >= (defaultLevelDepth + zOffset))
        {
            proj->getPoolOwner()->releaseAProjectile(proj);
            //(*listIter) = NULL; // THIS ERRORS, also tried = 0.
            //listIter = m_downDirectionList.erase(listIter); // THIS ALSO ERRORS
        }

        else
        {
            (*listIter)->update(camera, zOffset);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Clarification, just having this line.

```
listIter = m_downDirectionList.erase(listIter);
```

this also errors.

Comment: I don't know what `m_downDirectionList` is, really, or what `releaseAProjectile` does.  Nor do I know what sort of error, or your testing techniques, or whether the error is consistent.

Comment: About the edit. If you're referring to my solution, I did more than just adding that line. I also moved the iterator increment to the else block. I was going to edit my answer with an explanation after I posted but [Kos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305002/erasing-a-pointer-from-a-vector/4305045#4305045) already explained the issue.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728551/c-iterators-problem/2728567 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(listIter = m_downDirectionList.begin(); listIter != m_downDirectionList.end(); )
    {
        Projectile* proj = dynamic_cast<Projectile*>(*listIter);

        if (proj->getZWorldCoord() >= (defaultLevelDepth + zOffset))
        {
            proj->getPoolOwner()->releaseAProjectile(proj);
            listIter = m_downDirectionList.erase(listIter);
        }

        else
        { //m_downDirectionList[p]->update(camera, zOffset);
            (*listIter)->update(camera, zOffset);
            listIter++
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also correct and elegant (my wee remark about ++listIter still holds, though :))

Comment: It should be noted that this works because it is a vector (yes, it's clear, but the question and the answer are far away spatially...).

Answer (score 0):

```
  m_downDirectionList.erase (listIter);
```